# Cannot properly merge two .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

There are 2 `.htaccess` files, one in `/` and the second in `/web` folders.

In a root folder (`/`), `.htaccess` looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ web/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) web/$1 [L]
```

In `/web` folder, `.htaccess` looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works perfectly.

All I want is to merge those conditions and put them inside a single `.htaccess` that would be in root directory (`/`).

#### 1 - I've tried to add `RewriteBase`, like

`RewriteBase /web`

#### 2 - I've tried to replace conditions that aware of web folder

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

#### 3 - I've tried to simply append a config from one file to another with slight alterations.

But none of this works - It gives internal 500 server error.

How a proper merging should be done in this case?

Comment: _“It gives internal 500 server error”_ – when then the first thing you should do is look into the error log!

Answer (score 2):

This `.htaccess` (in the root folder) should match to your needs :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting all the rules in your document root (`/`) then try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```